# Missing Required Icons error when the icons are presesent

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to iTunes Connect, but it keeps giving me the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for
iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
```

as well as

```
WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing 
Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for 
App Review or Beta App Review."
```

This would be ok if these icons were actually missing, but they are all present in an App Icon Set on xcode. This is linked to from `App Icons and Launch Images`. My upload was working yesterday, but I have since updated to High Sierra on my mac and now it gives me this error. I have tried removing the app icons, and re-adding them back in but it's not working! Why is it giving me this error?

Screenshot of assets:

[image: AppIcon asset]

Comment: Can u add a screen shot of your XCAssets?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh updated

Comment: In general target settings, are you actually using the asset you've screenshotted?

Comment: Are you using beta version of Xcode?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I think this is an issue with using the beta, try uploading using a released version of Xcode

Comment: Its the Xcode 9 GM release, I'll try using the version from the app store... And yeah I am using the assets I've screenshotted

Comment: Nope still gives the same error!!

Comment: We have a pretty long thread going in Apple developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290?sr=stream Still no word from Apple...

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I saw that, it's the exact same issue. Have partially solved it by running some code someone suggested, but it still gave me a "no marketing icon" warning. Hurry up Apple!

Comment: i solved this problem by link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885406/4305700