# Missing Marketing Icon Xcode bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've added a 1024 pt icon to the app as necessary. Here, it is on a screenshot:
[image]
But when I try to upload it to the AppStore - it says I don't have it.

Here when I try to choose Icon assets in Xcode - it strangely give me options only to use AppIcon file from the libraries which are empty and nonexistent, not giving me an option to use Assets from my Assets file in project
[image]
Here on a picture all these options are from the library and empty
[image]

So, as a result I can't use my real icons and get this warning :

[image]

Anybody know how to solve this issue??

Comment: 1) Verify that your icon has PNG format (not JPG or ohther) 2) Try to Clean/Rearchive your project 3) Relaunch Xcode 4) Reboot 5) Just pray

Comment: in `Assets.xcassets`, just add 1024x1024 icon with .png extension and without alpha contains.

Comment: @NiravKotecha I already did it, you may see by screenshot

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this problem yesterday,i spent a whole day and finally i solved this problem.

Here is my environment

1.cocoapod

2.macOS Sierra/macOS High Sierra

3.Xcode 9

First of all,make sure you have already set the assets which cantains appicon,and make sure you have set the 1024*1024 icon for App Store.
If so,you still get the problem while uploading the binary to App Store.Then there are two situations.

[image]
[image]

### If you use cocoapod

**Also,you can not see the app icon properly after you run you app on you device.**It's because [cocoapod's bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003).Open the project directory,open the file whose path is [PROJECT_NAME]/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-[PROJECT_NAME]/Pods-[PROJECT_NAME]-resources.sh,pull to the end,replace the code

`printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform "${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target "${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --compress-pngs --compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
fi`

to

`printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform "${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target "${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --compress-pngs --compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"
fi`

then run your app,you can see the right app icon now and you can also upload binary properly.If it still does not work, use the following method.

### If you don't use cocoapod,

it's a bug of [APFS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Once your app was archived right click it and choose show in Finder. Open the package contents and open this file inside of it:  /Products/Application/yourApp.app/info.plist

In there you have to change all the DTXXX Values to be the same as in the latest version of Xcode 8.

> DTXcode - “0833”
>   DTSDKName - “iphoneos10.3"
>   DTSDKBuild - “14E8301”
>   DTPlatformName - “iphoneos”
>   DTCompiler - “com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0”
>   DTXcodeBuild - “8E3004b”
>   DTPlatformVersion - “10.3”
>   DTPlatformBuild - “14E8301"

Save the plist file and go back to xcode where you need to export the archive for the App Store.

Last but not least download [Application Loader 3.0](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg) from Apple and upload the just generated IPA file.

Comment: holy crap it was indeed cocoapods, I thought I was stumped. Hopefully they've fixed this in the newest version of cocoapods but crap allmighty this was a bad bug.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue few weeks back, though I had added the marketing icon of 1024 X 1024 with .png format and no alpha channel in the Xcode, the submission was denied and failed continuously with warning as shown below:

---

### WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review

I am not fully sure about the cause of issue whether it is because of Xcode 9 or Mac OS High sierra or Cocoa-pods, but I could solved the issue with following :

- Added the 1024 X 1024 .png Appstoreicon with no alpha channel.
- Archieve the Xcode project. (Just do Archieve, do not upload or export .ipa in this step.)
- Locate your app's .xcarchive file clicking show in finder as shown below:

[image]

- Then right click -->> Show Package Contents, go to Products folder -->> Applications -->> on your application's name, again right click and -->> Show Package Contents. Locate the info plist from there (you can clean up files by clean by kind in order to locate info.plist fast).
- And change the BuildMachineOsBuild value to 16A323.

[image]

- Then save the .plist file
- Now export the .ipa file and upload that .ipa file to iTunes with Application loader.
- The app submission should success, even with the WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing Icon.

Hope it works for your case too.

The thread discussion is here:
[Marketing icon missing issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462434/missing-required-icon-issue-and-marketing-icon-not-found-issue)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it didn't help. In Itunesconnect it still say me "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just dragged and dropped all icons to the assets. It fixed the problem

Answer (score -3):

You can ignore those Error. You can upload a marketing image on iTunes Connect later.

Comment: This is not true. The build will be rejected during upload to AppStore.

Comment: @Peiper sometimes apple not allow to submit apps in itunes connect. if you don't upload marketing icon