# ipa file where 1024 icons can be found？

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I did not find the 1024 icon in the ipa package, may I ask where the picture is, if not in the ipa file, then why not upload the package when there is no 1024 icon, or transparency, please advise! thank you!

Comment: This might be helpful for you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771321/missing-marketing-icon-xcode-bug

Comment: @MdRashedPervez  Thank you for your reply, I want to know is that the 1024 icon is placed in the ipa file inside that, not want to know where the configuration in xcode ah. Because this ipa package is someone else, so I want to see if ipa can find this 1024 icon?

Answer (score 0):

I find that is github AssetCatalogTinkerer: https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer!

same quesion: [Analysing Assets.car file in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios)